# How to back press android

Tags: android

I am new to android, I am called fragmentbell from my fragmenthome then I am called fragmentbell from fragmenthome. That is  not working . When I Press back button from fragmenthome it's not working (I want to go back to fragmenthome)  m trying to override onbackpressed method inside fragment . But it gives me syntax error that it should override a super method in interface

```
`public class Fragmentbell extends Fragment {
LinearLayout linearLayout;
private View root_view;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private Adapterbell adapterbell;
public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";
DbHandler databaseHandler;

private ArrayList<bell> mNotificationList;

private ShimmerFrameLayout lyt_shimmer;
SharedPref sharedPref;
private List<bell> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bell, container, false);


   
    loadDataFromDatabase();

    recyclerView = root_view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacingItemDecoration(0));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    adapterbell = new Adapterbell(getActivity(), recyclerView, data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterbell);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),    DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));



    adapterbell.setOnItemClickListener(( v, obj, position ) -> {


        databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());

        databaseHandler.updateStatus(data.get(position).getId(), true);


        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showInterstitialAd();





        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityNotificationDetail.class);



        Log.v("testti", "" + v.getTag() + " apakah sama " + data.get(position).getpost_id());


        this.startActivity(intent);


    });









    return root_view;
}


private void loadDataFromDatabase() {
    databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());
    data = databaseHandler.getAllbell();

}






public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentHome  bell=new FragmentHome();



    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment1, bell);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
}`
```

fragmentbell to fragmenthome back press not working android

Comment: `onBackpressed` is activity method, not in fragment.

Comment: @GHH fragmentbell to fragmenthome not go backprss click how to slove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addToBackStack(@Nullable String name)` will help. When start Fragmentbell from Fragmenthome, you can add the transaction to backstack like this:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.Fragment1, bell).addToBackStack("Fragmentbell");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

So it will add Fragmenthome -> Fragmentbell to backstack. When press back, the reverse version Fragmenthome <- Fragmentbell will be processed and navigate to Fragmenthome